# Problem Splitting Code at '%2F', not at '/'

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

So, I'm working on a bookmarklet that takes the website url, which contains the actual text '%2F' in it, and split it there. However, because %2F represents a forward slash, it keeps splitting where there are forward slashes and not at %2F. How can I fix this?

Current Code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        var str = window.location.href;
        var res = str.split("%2F");
        alert(res); //Just here to test the output
    }
)
();
```

Example Input:
http://blocked.com-default.ws/?oI=14697520135&type=chromium-m&url=i.imgur.com%2F4uHAdNPg.jpg

Example Output:
http:,,blocked.com-default.ws/?oI=14697520135&type=chromium-m&url=i.imgur.com%2F4uHAdNPg.jpg

Wanted Output:
http://blocked.com-default.ws/?oI=14697520135&type=chromium-m&url=i.imgur.com ,4uHAdNPg.jpg

Comment: You can use decodeURI('window.location.href'), which replaces each escape sequence in the encoded URI with the character that it represents

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want you focus your splitting more to a specific portion of the location rather that the whole URL. In your case, it looks like you really want to split the value of the `url` variable which is found in `window.location.search`. You can probably accomplish close what you want if you just use that instead of `window.location.href`.

A better approach might be to target the actual value of the `url` variable.If you don't need to support IE, an easy way to get that data is to use `UrlSearchParams`:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const url = params.get("url");
const res = url.split('%2F');
```

If you do need more cross browser reach, you can also do this with a simple regular expression:

```
const url = window.location.search.match(/url=[^&]+/)
const res = url.split('%2F');
```

Answer (score 0):

The split works as expected:

```js
const str = 'http://blocked.com-default.ws/?oI=14697520135&type=chromium-m&url=i.imgur.com%2F4uHAdNPg.jpg';
console.log(str.split('%2F'));
```

But `window.location.href` doesn't always return exactly the same string that is being displayed in the address bar, or encode stuff without you knowing about it. It is quite browser-dependent. For example, on chrome, you might observe this:

```
location.href = 'http://example.com/ xxx';
console.log(location.href); // http://example.com/%20xxx
```

---

In any case, it just looks like you're trying to manipulate your URL *by hand*. Don't do that. By using `new URL(...)`, `location.searchParams`, `decodeURIComponent`, and other native APIs to easily manipulate URLs, you'll probably achieve what you're looking for in an easier and safer way ;)